# Capturing checkbox event in a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am using a list view containing check boxes. Could you please help me how to identify which check box has the user selected? Basically I want different functions to be performed when a checkbox is clicked or a list item is selected similar to Android alarm clock.

Comment: You will sound more intelligent if you don't use "words" like "u" and "Plzzz"(Correct punctuation helps too). People are more likely to help if you spell them out.  Also, try searching for a similar question before asking one.

Answer (score 0):

does this help you:

[how to display a list of checkboxes using dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054716/how-to-display-a-list-of-checkboxes-using-dynamic-data)

That is how I did it with dynamic data.

Basically, in your listView class override:

```
@override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  boolean isClicked = l.isItemChecked(position);
  // do something
}
```

Comment: hey Ekawas i am still stuck to the the same problem.....i want different functions to be performed when checkbox is clicked or listitem is selected......please help

Comment: whats the problem? in your listview, override onListItemClick() and from inside call whatever method you need to... am i missing something?